# Factor analysis when I have mixture of continuous and dichotomous variables

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, ancova, mixed-type-data

I am trying to determine if there is a significant difference between two groups for a single continuous variable while accounting for baseline differences in dichotomous variables in each group.

To provide a simplified example, I want to compare the height of two groups but the proportions of male/female, healthy/unhealthy, old/young, BMI etc ... (most of which are binary variables aside from a few like BMI) differ. Thus, I would like to run an ANCOVA but am unsure which variables to include in the model. The main issue here is that I have so many covariates (8) that I would like to perform factor analysis to determine which to include, but traditional methods of factor analysis do not work with dichotomous or mixed data.

Can anyone recommend a particular method to determine this? I have heard of using VSS and Velicer's MAP when you have only continuous variables, but I am unsure what to do with binary covariates and a continuous independent variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Why can't you do ancova with all of your variables as covariates?

Comment: I could, but I am attempting to perform factor analysis so that I don't over-include variables in my model. Sorry if that was unclear before. Thanks!

Comment: If they're covariates, they aren't a problem, unless you have a very large number - or a small sample size. By doing factor analysis you remove some variance from the covariates, and so control for them less well.